# Caused by : java.io.NotserializableException : android.app.Instrumentation

Tags: android, serialization

I have written a service which implements Serializable, and I have made all customized classes to be serializable. But there are errors when running the project: 
*

```
Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object Caused by : java.io.NotserializableException : android.app.Instrumentation`
```

*
The problem is seemed to be caused by using "android.app.Instrumentation". Can't we make one class serializable if it use `android.app.Instrumentation`? I am confused. Thanks!

Comment: `Service` shouldn't be pass as `Parcelable` ... all `Service` objects/instances should be creatad by Android OS ... so even if you could write it to Parcel instance creatad by Parcelable.CREATOR will not be valid Service ... you should consider using AIDL http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html for comunication between Service and other Application components